# How do I create a prompt using wxpython?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have the following code:

```
 try:
     redirect_url = self.auth.get_authorization_url()
     webbrowser.open_new(redirect_url)
 except tweepy.TweepError:
     print 'Error! Failed to get request token.'

     verifier=raw_input("Enter verification code: ")

 try:
     self.auth.get_access_token(verifier)
     print "Access granted"
     self.__key,self.__secret = self.auth.access_token.key,self.auth.access_token.secret
     self.set_tokens(self.__key,self.__secret)
     print self.__key, self.__secret
 except tweepy.TweepError:
     print "Error! Failed to get access token!"
```

How do I stop the the second try-except block from executing when implementing wx.Frame. e.g. so that the it doesn't proceed until a Button has been pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the second block be just put into the button press callback? Something like

```
proceed_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.process_auth_tokens)
```

where `process_auth_tokens` is your second block.

You might want to run the event handler on a separate thread if it does network I/O, though.